# How to call an array of scopes on an ActiveRecord object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an `Article` model which has `recent`, `compiled`, `featured` scopes. I can chain these scopes like this:

```
Article.recent.compiled.featured
```

Now I have an array of these scopes:

```
scopes = [:recent, :compiled, :featured]
or
scopes = [:recent, :compiled]
```

I don't know beforehand how many scopes are there in the `scopes` variable. I just know it's an array of scopes.

How can I use this array as a chain of scopes to be called on the `Article` model as mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just use inject:

```
scopes.inject(Article){ |ar,scope| ar.send(scope) }
```

Comment: Cool it works! Any way to put Article in the front like `Article.send(*rest of the code*)`?

Comment: You can add a method who does that: 
`class ActiveRecord::Base
 def with_scopes(*scopes)
  scopes.inject(self){ |relation, scope| relation.send(scope) }
 end
end`