# How to dynamically call scopes with 'OR' clause from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an array, and I'd like to call scopes with `OR` clause:

```
cars = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota']

class Car < AR
  scope :from_bmw, -> { where(type: 'bmw') }
  scope :from_audi, -> { where(type: 'audi') }
  scope :from_toyota, -> { where(type: 'toyota') }
end
```

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
Car.from_bmw.or(Car.from_audi).or(Car.from_toyota)
```

My `cars` array can change; in case: `cars = ['toyota', 'audi']`, my method should produce:

```
Car.from_toyota.or(Car.from_audi)
```

I have something like the following:

```
def generate(cars)
  scopes = cars.map {|f| "from_#{f} "}

  scopes.each do |s|
    # HOW TO I ITERATE OVER HERE AND CALL EACH SCOPE???
  end
end
```

I don't want to pass type as an argument to scope, there's a reason behind it.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27082253/how-to-call-an-array-of-scopes-on-an-activerecord-object

Comment: You can do a simple `Car.where(type: cars)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def generate(cars)
  return Car.none if cars.blank?
  scopes = cars.map {|f| "from_#{f} "}

  scope = Car.send(scopes.shift)

  scopes.each do |s|
    scope = scope.or(Car.send(s))
  end

  scope
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the given array contains only valid `type` values, you could simply do that:

```
class Car
  scope :by_type, -> (type) { where(type: type) }
end

types = ['bmw', 'audi', 'toyota']

Car.by_type(types) # => It'll generate a query using IN: SELECT * FROM cars WHERE type IN ('bmw', 'audi', 'toyota')
```

If you don't want to pass the array as an argument to scope for whatever reason, you could create a hash mapping the array values to valid `by_type` arguments.

```
VALID_CAR_TYPES = { volkswagen: ['vw', 'volkswagen'], bmw: ['bmw'], ...  }
def sanitize_car_types(types)
  types.map do |type|
    VALID_CAR_TYPES.find { |k, v| v.include?(type) }.first
  end.compact
end


Car.by_type(sanitize_car_types(types))
```